# jquery select input field search

Tags: javascript, fuzzy-search

How can I create an input field that automatically narrows the options in a selectbox?

I have a selectbox with hundred names and it would be nice if you could enter anything fuzzy in the input field, so the selectbox only shows the fitting names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked here: [JavaScript fuzzy search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9206013/javascript-fuzzy-search#15252131)?

There are a couple of external links which may be useful and also a couple of attempts at fuzzy search which you may be able to use.

You could trigger any function you do decide to use by watching for [key up](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keyup) in the input field.